# Entity Framework 6 Migrations with views

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I need to map to a view when using EF6 with migrations.

The view pivots 2 other tables to enable a simple summary view of the underlying data, the idea being it allows us to use this in a summary index view.

The issue I have is I am unable create a migration that either deploys the view (ideal goal) or deploys the DB without the view for later manual deployment.

In most attempts, following other SO questions, I end up either deadlocking the `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` commands or generally causing an error that breaks one or the other.

What is the current best way to use EF6 to access views, even if I lose the ability to automatically deploy them with the migrations, and not cause errors with migrations.

#### Further detail

The Db contains 2 tables Reports and ReportAnswers.  The view ReportView combines these two and pivots ReportAnswers to allow some of the rows to become columns in this summary view.

Reports and ReportAnswers were depolied via EF Migrations.  The view is currently a script that needs be added to the deployment somehow.

Reports, ReportAnswers & ReportView are accessible from the db Context

```
public virtual DbSet<ReportAnswer> ReportAnswers { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Report> Reports { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<ReportView> ReportView { get; set; }
```

I have tried using `Add-Migration Name -IgnoreChanges` to create a blank migration and then manually adding the view to the `Up()` and `Down()` methods but this just deadlocks the migration and update commands, each wanting the other to run first.

I have also tried using `modelBuilder.Ignore<ReportView>();` to ignore the type when running the migrations but this proved incredibly error prone, even though it did seem to work at least once.

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to make this work.  Most people don't use migrations _and_ views or stored procedures.  You can just manually keep your EF model and your database compatible, or generate the EF model from the database.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft That does seem to be the case. Though now as EF is a pretty mature product you think that at least some basic View/SP support would be there. I guess I'll just hide it all in the DAL.

Answer (score 4):

I just walked around interesting article about using views with EF Core few days ago, but I found also the very same using EF 6.

You may want to use `Seed` method instead of migration `Up` and `Down` methods.

```
protected override void Seed({DbContextType} context)
{
    string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
    UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
    string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
    var baseDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path) + "\\Migrations\\{CreateViewSQLScriptFilename}.sql";

    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(File.ReadAllText(baseDir));
}
```

Your SQL command should look like sample below.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[{ViewName}]'))
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE VIEW [dbo].[{ViewName}]
AS
SELECT {SelectCommand}
```

It is not perfect, but I hope at least helpful.

I found another blog post about this topic and the writer says to use `Sql(@"CREATE VIEW dbo.{ViewName} AS...")` in `Up` method and `Sql(@"DROP VIEW dbo.{ViewName};")` in `Down` method. I added it as you didn't supplied the code from `Up` and `Down` migration methods. Maybe good idea will be to add SqlFile instead of Sql method.

There is also option to create customized code or sql generator and plug it in to migrations, but I guess it is not the things you are looking for.

Let me know in comment in case you need additional help.

Related links:

[Using Views with Entity Framework Code First](https://srramalho.wordpress.com/2016/04/29/using-views-with-entity-framework-code-first/)

[EF CODE FIRST - VIEWS AND STORED PROCEDURES](http://vborza.com/codefirst-views-stored-procs/)

[Leveraging Views in Entity Framework](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Blogs/Tool-Tracker/2015/02/Leverage-Views-in-Entity-Framework.aspx)

[DbMigration.Sql Method (String, Boolean, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.sql(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigration.Sql(System.String,System.Boolean,System.Object))

[DbMigration.SqlFile Method (String, Boolean, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.sqlfile(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigration.SqlFile(System.String,System.Boolean,System.Object))

Comment: Thanks, my `Up()` and `Down()` do what you describe.  It looks like my way forwards is to use either a migration or a Seed method to add the view and then use a more manual access in the DAL rather than just calling in via the normal EF methods as those seem to be the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Did you try to map view with `[Table("{ViewName}")]` attribute or `modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>().ToTable("{ViewName}");` method? As you didn't provide enought of code, it is not clear.

Comment: I believe I did, I went through dozens of attempts to get it to work hence little code.  Mapping wasn't so much the issue, it was more mapping it in a way that works with functioning migrations.

Comment: I think the issue with migrations is that EF can't recognize if the mapping is table or view. Maybe the way to deal with it is to introduce new attribute and add logic to CSharpCodeGenerator. But I guess it is nothing simple.